# Simplest way to remove multiple unnecessary character from a batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

These lines of code should remove these characters `":>&|` from `!txtl!`

```
set txtl=!txtl:"=!
set txtl=!txtl::=!
set txtl=!txtl:^>=!
set txtl=!txtl:^&=!
set txtl=!txtl:^|=!
```

But it looks very inefficient, I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the unnecessary characters using just one command.

Comment: Not unless your command is a third party script/tool with regex like capabilities. And using a third part tool may look more efficient but it may not perform the task any quicker than using multiple set commands in sequence, as you already have. Perhaps you should explain what you mean by 'inefficient', or perhaps more precisely, by 'looks very inefficient'!

Comment: You do not need to escape characters if you use this syntax: `set "txtl=!txtl:|=!"`

Comment: You could simplify it a bit with a `FOR` command. `for %%G in (">" "&" "|" ":") DO set "txt1=!txt1:%%~G=!"`

Comment: Just bear in mind that the `for` loop is still running in sequence the same number of `set` commands, and is therefore no more efficient. The only 'efficiency' to be had is in the time taken to type, once only, the batch file, and I wouldn't term that as 'very inefficient'!

Comment: Alrighty, so i should stay using that command